# Retrieve list of accounts with specific classification

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, auxil-excel-add-in

I want to retrieve a list of customer names and a list of the assigned account manager and region as registered using a custom property.

Using the following query, I get multiple lines per customer:

```
select accountclassifications_account_name
,      property_code_attr
,      property_description
from   exactonlinexml..accountclassifications 
where  property_code_attr in ( 'BO', 'REGION' )
```

But I would like to have one field with both the account manager and region. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the group function `listagg` you can retrieve multiple values per customer account:

```
select accountclassifications_account_name
,      listagg(property_code_attr || ': ' || property_description) lst
from   exactonlinexml..accountclassifications 
where  property_code_attr in ( 'BO', 'REGION' )
group 
by     accountclassifications_account_name
```

When you need a different separator, you can specify it as a separate parameter to `listagg`.